# I need a help with apt(annoying message)

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.04

I made a script and moved it to /usr/bin, then i removed it, but now when i try to use apt to update or upgrade and install something, i get that message at the end "sh: 1: /usr/bin/test: not found"("test" was the name of the script), can someone help me, this is really annoying, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/test` is an important system utility, provided by the `coreutils` package. When you moved your script `test` to `/usr/bin` you overwrote it.

You should be able to reinstall it using

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

If the missing `test` binary is preventing `apt` from running at all, then you can probably replace it temporarily with a link to `/bin/busybox` just so that `apt install --reinstall` can complete

---

In the future, resist the urge to use `/usr/bin` for non-system scripts or programs - put personal scripts in `~/bin` and site-wide ones in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Omg, thanks man, you're awesome, it worked, and thanks for the tips

Comment: @paparoxo360 happy to help - in the interests of science, was it necessary to link `/usr/bin/test` to `/bin/busybox` or did `apt install --reinstall` work without it?

Comment: I just did the sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils.

Comment: @paparoxo360 OK thanks that's useful to know

Comment: I agree with steeldriver (as for location of your own utilities), but if I wanted to call a script `test`, I do a `whereis test` before I name the script; which responds `/usr/bin/test /usr/share/man/man1/test.1.gz` (ie. `test` is located in /usr/bin/ with `man` reference manual page (1) in /usr/share/man/man1/ . Thus I know it's used, so I'd pick a new name, eg. `whereis blah` & get no response, telling me I can call my script 'blah' far more safely  (as there is no program/script that uses that name in my $PATH)...